# Ordering list of users by last name and then by first name

Tags: users, wpdb

I have a page listing users with certain custom roles, ordered by last name in alphabetical order. So far, so good. The problem is when two users have the same last name (i.e. John Doe and Rick Doe). Is there a way that is not too resource-intensive to make sure when this happens the alphabetical listing is also considering the first name after sorting the list by last name, to ensure that John Doe comes BEFORE than Rick Doe in the list? Here is my code, which only loops through last_name:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'meta_key' => 'last_name',
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'OR',
array(
'key' => $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities',
'value' => 'shop_worker',
'compare' => 'like'
),
array(
'key' => $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities',
'value' => 'shop_vendor',
'compare' => 'like'
),
array(
'key' => $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities',
'value' => 'shop_accountant',
'compare' => 'like'
),
array(
'key' => $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities',
'value' => 'contributor',
'compare' => 'like'
),
array(
'key' => $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities',
'value' => 'author',
'compare' => 'like'
)
)
) );

if (!empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
?>
<div class="entry clearfix user-profile">
<div class="user-data">
<h2><?php echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url($user->ID) ) . '">' .
 esc_attr( $user->display_name ) . '</a>'; ?></h2>
<?php
if (!empty($user->profile_title)) {
echo '<div class="profile-subtitle">', $user->profile_title,'</div>';
}
if (!empty($user->profile_company)) {
echo '<small class="profile-company">', $user->profile_company,'</small>';
}
?>

</div>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: To be really honest, I know I have answered the same exact question before, when, I don`t know. Please feel free to dig through my answers :-)

Comment: I cannot seem to find it. There are a few questions regarding last_name, but they don't solve the problem of same last_name users...